# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roleId' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I have a requirement that requires me to validate if a user is selecting a correct manager. The association between them is the group id each belongs to. A user can be associated to one group id and a manager can be associated to more than one group id. When allowing a user to select his manager, I need to validate if the user's group id exists in the manager's list of group ids. Here is the code i have implemented below but I get **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roleId' of undefined**

My route file account.ts has the following codeblock

```
let promise = accountController.update(user);
        promise.then(function(data) {
            if (data.IsSuccessful == true)
            {
                result.IsSuccessful = true;
                result.SuccessMessage = process.env.USER_UPDATED || "User changed";
                return res.status(200).json(result);
            } 
            else 
            {
                result.IsSuccessful = false;
                result.ReasonForFailure = data.ReasonForFailure;
                res.status(200).json(result);
            }
        }).catch(function(err){
            result.IsSuccessful = false;
            result.ReasonForFailure = err.message;
            res.status(200).json(result);
        });
```

My controller file account.ts has the following code block for the update method

```
update = (account: Account) : Promise<Result<Account>> => {
        var thisObj = this;
        return new Promise<Result<Account>>(function (resolve, reject){
            let result = new Result<Account>();
            result.Data = account;
            MongoClient.connect(config.database.uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true } , async function(err: any, db: any) {
                if (err) {
                   // throw err;
                   result.IsSuccessful = false;
                   result.ReasonForFailure = err.message;
                   reject(result);
               } 
                   
                var dbo = db.db(config.database.name);
                   
                var newvalues = { $set: 
                    {
                        name: account.name,
                        title: account.title,
                        organization: account.organization,
                        reportingTo: account.reportingTo,
                        workNumber: account.workNumber,
                        mobileNumber: account.mobileNumber,
                        allowNotification: account.allowNotification,
                        allowEmail: account.allowEmail,
                        groups: account.groups,
                        updatedDate: account.updatedDate,
                        isProfileSetupComplete: true,
                        photo:account.photo
                    }
                };
                
                let existingUser: any;
                var query = {email:account.email};
                
                var resultArray = await dbo.collection("users").find(query).toArray();

                if (resultArray.length > 0) {
                    existingUser = resultArray[0];                        
                } else {
                    db.close();
                    result.ReasonForFailure = process.env.INVALID_USER_ID || "Invalid User Id";
                    result.IsSuccessful = false;
                    reject(result);
                }

                console.log(existingUser);
                if (existingUser.roleId == "1") { //roleId="1" means user
                    //validate manager id. reportingTo id must be a manager

                    var queryReporting = { _id: account.reportingTo };
                    let managerUser: any;
                    var resultManagerArray = await dbo.collection("users").find(queryReporting).toArray();
                    if (resultManagerArray.length > 0) {
                        console.log("managerUser in");//<--This is not printing in the console log
                        managerUser = resultManagerArray[0];                        
                    } else {
                        db.close();
                        result.ReasonForFailure = "Invalid reporting id.";// process.env.INVALID_USER_ID || "Invalid User Id";
                        result.IsSuccessful = false;
                        resolve(result);                        
                    }                    

                    //validate manager user
                    console.log("managerUser out");
                    console.log(managerUser);
                    if (managerUser.roleId !== "2"){//<--UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roleId' of undefined
                        result.IsSuccessful = false;
                        result.ReasonForFailure = "Reporting to must be a Manager";
                        reject(result);
                    } 

                    //manager and user must be associated with same group
                    if (!managerUser.groups.includes(account.groups)) {
                        result.IsSuccessful = false;
                        result.ReasonForFailure = "Incorrect Manager selection. Employee must be associated with a group the manager is associated with."
                        reject(result);
                    }
                }

                dbo.collection("users").updateOne(query, newvalues, function(err: any, resultSet: any) {
                    if (err) {
                        //throw err;
                        db.close();
                        result.IsSuccessful = false;
                        result.ReasonForFailure = err.message;
                        reject(result);
                    } else {
                        result.SuccessMessage = oldImage;
                        result.IsSuccessful = true;
                        db.close();
                        resolve(result);
                    }
                });
             });
        });
    }
```

managerUser.roleId !== "2" in the above code is the place where I get the **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roleId' of undefined**

I have put await in first call to the find query and it worked as expected waiting for the call to finish but the next await has no effect it seems. The execution didn't wait for the call to finish.

Can you please assist what I'm missing here?

Thanks,
Hemant.

Comment: you should add a `return` statement when you run `resolve or reject` since your code continues to run

Comment: Don't pass an `async function` as a callback

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon and Bergi, thank you for the solution. Adding the return before the resolve did the trick.

Comment: @Bergi, can you please clarify where I'm passing async function as callback that needs to be fixed. I'm learning and this can help me.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. If additional details can be provided as to why this was downvoted can help.

Comment: @Hemant I was referring to `MongoClient.connect(… , async function(err: any, db: any) { … })`. See my answer below for how to fix it - `MongoClient.connect` returns a promise when you don't pass a callback, so you can just `await` it.

Comment: @Bergi, Thank you very much for your guidance. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably missing `return` statements after all the `resolve(result);`/`reject(result);` calls. Unlike `return` and `throw`, they're ordinary function calls and do not terminate the execution of the function.

Additionally you shouldn't pass an `async function` as a callback to a function that doesn't handle the returned promise. You should only promisify the `connect` call alone, wait for its result, and continue the rest of your function after `await` or in a `then` callback to ensure errors are handled appropriately.

```
update = async (account: Account) : Promise<Result<Account>> => {
    let result = new Result<Account>();
    result.Data = account;
    try {
        const db = await MongoClient.connect(config.database.uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
        try {
            const dbo = db.db(config.database.name);

            const newvalues = {
                $set: {
                    name: account.name,
                    title: account.title,
                    organization: account.organization,
                    reportingTo: account.reportingTo,
                    workNumber: account.workNumber,
                    mobileNumber: account.mobileNumber,
                    allowNotification: account.allowNotification,
                    allowEmail: account.allowEmail,
                    groups: account.groups,
                    updatedDate: account.updatedDate,
                    isProfileSetupComplete: true,
                    photo:account.photo
                }
            };
            var resultArray = await dbo.collection("users").find({email: account.email}).toArray();

            if (resultArray.length == 0) {
                result.ReasonForFailure = process.env.INVALID_USER_ID || "Invalid User Id";
                result.IsSuccessful = false;
                return result;
            }
            const existingUser = resultArray[0];
            console.log(existingUser);

            if (existingUser.roleId == "1") {
                var resultManagerArray = await dbo.collection("users").find({ _id: account.reportingTo }).toArray();
                if (resultManagerArray.length == 0) {
                    result.ReasonForFailure = "Invalid reporting id.";// process.env.INVALID_USER_ID || "Invalid User Id";
                    result.IsSuccessful = false;
                    return result;
                }
                console.log("managerUser in");
                const managerUser = resultManagerArray[0];
                console.log("managerUser out");
                console.log(managerUser);

                if (managerUser.roleId !== "2") {
                    result.IsSuccessful = false;
                    result.ReasonForFailure = "Reporting to must be a Manager";
                    return result;
                }

                //manager and user must be associated with same group
                if (!managerUser.groups.includes(account.groups)) {
                    result.IsSuccessful = false;
                    result.ReasonForFailure = "Incorrect Manager selection. Employee must be associated with a group the manager is associated with."
                    return result;
                }
            }

            const resultSet = await dbo.collection("users").updateOne(query, newvalues);
            result.SuccessMessage = oldImage;
            result.IsSuccessful = true;
            return result;
        } finally {
            db.close()
        }
    } catch(err) {
        result.IsSuccessful = false;
        result.ReasonForFailure = err.message;
        return result;
    }
};
```